# Iteratively running through list of parameter sets with ParametricNDSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So I have the below code

```
perturb1 = 
  x'[t] == mu1*x[t] + x[t]*(a*x[t] + b*y[t] + c*z[t]) + 
    x[t]*eps1 * (UnitStep[t - 1.5] - UnitStep[t - 2.5]);
perturb2 = 
  y'[t] == mu2*y[t] + y[t]*(d*x[t] + e*y[t] + f*z[t]) + 
    y[t]*eps2 * (UnitStep[t - 1.5] - UnitStep[t - 2.5]);
perturb3 = 
  z'[t] == mu3*z[t] + z[t]*(g*x[t] + h*y[t] + i*z[t]) + 
    z[t]*eps3 * (UnitStep[t - 1.5] - UnitStep[t - 2.5]);
perturbSol = ParametricNDSolve[
   {perturb1, perturb2, perturb3, x[0] == 0.25, y[0] == 0.4, 
    z[0] == 0.35},
   {x[t], y[t], z[t]},
   {t, 0, 500},
   {mu1, mu2, mu3, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, eps1, eps2, eps3}
   ];
Evaluate[x[t][#] /. perturbSol] & /@ parameterSets
```

`parameterSets` is a list of 5000+ elements of the form {mu1, mu2, mu3, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, eps1, eps2, eps3} (but with numerical values). What I'm trying to do is to evaluate the parametric function using each parameter set. When I do as above, I get the error

```
ParametricNDSolve: Too many parameters in {mu1,mu2,mu3,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,eps1,eps2,eps3} to be filled from {{0.9,0.9,0.9,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2}}.
```

So it seems that it's because, with a single value, you would evaluate the function as follows:

```
Evaluate[x[t][0.9,0.9,0.9,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2]/.perturbSol]
```

Whereas when using Map on parameterSets, it does this:

```
Evaluate[x[t][{0.9,0.9,0.9,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2}]/.perturbSol]
```

i.e. it's applying the function to a list of 15 parameters, rather than to the 15 parameters separated by commas.

Is there any elegant solution to this? I tried flatten around the #, which didn't do anything (as I sort of expected). I guess one way is to write #1,#2,#3 etc in the square brackets but that's pretty messy.

Any better way to do this?

Many thanks,

H

Comment: Your likelyhood of getting an anwer will increase if you post this on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you want something along the lines of

```
u = ParametricNDSolveValue[{perturb1, perturb2, perturb3, 
    x[0] == 0.25, y[0] == 0.4, z[0] == 0.35}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
    500}, {mu1, mu2, mu3, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, eps1, eps2, 
    eps3}];
parameterSets = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 15}];

(u[##])[[1]][t] & @@@ parameterSets
```

Comment: Thanks, I just deleted this after you answered but undeleted since I saw your answer.

I ended up using 

    Evaluate[Apply[x[t], parameterSets, {1}] /. perturbSol]

But I think your answer should work too. Thank you.